# Computer freezing while doing any heavy task(s). Could this be hard drive failure?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, gaming

I'm on Windows 10, and whenever I'm doing some heavy task i.e. playing a game, I'm encountering random freezes which sometimes go in a few moments and sometimes stay for a minute or so and the game crashes.

One thing I noticed was the HDD LED (the one that shows disk activity) stays on whenever the freezing issue occurs. Could this mean hard disk failure? Checkdisk didn't show any bad sectors or errors, the computer works like a charm but sudden freezes are a pain.

Even tried reinstalling windows(formatted the HDD too). Still no fix.

Comment: Have you checked the disc's SMART data? Also, have you set a fixed page file size? Shortage of swap space could also explain your freeze.

Comment: Haven't done anything above-mentioned yet on the fresh windows installation

Comment: A fragmented page file can also cause huge amounts of disc activity when swapping is needed. You can check this with [PageDefrag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/pagedefrag), although I found that recent Windows releases have reported, but not allowed defragmentation.

Comment: That was the issue I guess. Ran checkdisk twice and then optimized the drive from the option under properties. Now it's working fine. Tho it had a few bad sectors but they're relocated now

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like hard drive failure. If it's an SSD, there's are many tools available to check (nearly all are free) here: https://www.enterprisestorageforum.com/storage-services/ssd-health-check-test-tools

You can always verify if it's the drive by replacing it with another one and see.

Something else that could be happening is that the computer is getting too hot, and the processor is getting overworked. I had this happen once. If you can get to the internal components, make sure all the fans are running, spray away any dust, etc. Ventilation is critical in these machines, so any hindrance, especially dust, could be the culprit.

Not sure video cards or RAM is the fault, but they could be.

Comment: Well I don't think it's processor or ventilation, the processor is a new one and the ventilation has been same for a year now. Ram is fine too (tested with a different ram) not sure about GPU tho. It's only a year old too though.